# Не работает автодополнение метода моделей

Tags: python, django, pycharm

есть модель к примеру:

```
from users.models import User
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    description = models.TextField()
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='products_images')
    category = models.ForeignKey(to=ProductCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

в контроллере вызывается, идет вызов этой модели

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from products.models import Product
def index(request):
    context={'title':Product.objects.all()}
    return render(request, 'products/index.html',context)
```

в результате все будет корректно работать, но PyCharm не будет показывать objects и его методы, с консоли всё работает, данная проблема появилась после обновления.
Консольное окно - [image: показывает поле objecs]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код - [image: не работает автодополнение]

Comment: Возможно поможет модуль https://pypi.org/project/django-types-extra/